# How to simulate a "myscript.py > mylog.txt"

Tags: python, logging

I try to implement an option which will save the console output additionally into a file. (**if** the option is activated)

I found two ways:
1. to use the logging module
2. to write a class like this:

```
class MyWriter: 
    def __init__(self, stdout, filename): 
        self.stdout = stdout 
        self.logfile = file(filename, 'a') 
    def write(self, text): 
        self.stdout.write(text) 
        self.logfile.write(text) 
    def close(self): 
        self.stdout.close() 
        self.logfile.close()
```

But I got a problem.
Some pieces of  code will execute in a new process. And this ways does not catch their prints.

When I start my program like

```
"myscript.py > mylog.txt"
```

it works. He got all prints. But how can I simulate this functionally in my script?

Comment: How do those processes get spawned?  Are you spawning those processes yourself or do they get called by some other support code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to redirect `stdout` of other process that you start right?

Then all you have to do is use

```
subprocess.Popen(...)
```

command. Then you have use your `MyWriter` class with it.

Comment: I use also this class in my new process. It works. Thank you guys.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion would be to use the logging module, to use a [sockethandler](http://docs.python.org/library/logging.handlers.html#sockethandler) and to push to a socket server that would write the received logs into a file.

I hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Problem probably has to be solved how you execute a new process, you either need to collect output from sub-process in main-process, or pass a filename to sub-process. You can use environment variables for filename instead of passing it as argument, then it will be easy to access log file in sub-process too.